# Vim alter text as or immediately after it's put

Tags: vim, substitution

Lately I've been `y`anking and `p`utting a lot of code that needs to be altered somewhat (usually just a simple substitution).  I can manually select it after it's pasted in, or for longer blocks I suppose I could look at the number of lines pasted (`20 new lines`) and use `20:s...`, but given that it's vim, it seems like there should be an easier/faster way to do this.

So is there a way to either select or execute a substitution on text as it's being `p`ut?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Immediately after the execution of the `p`, the `[` and `]` marks refer to the start and end line numbers of the pasted region (applies during `y` as well). See the help for `'[` and `']` for explanation.

Thus, you can use these marks to form the range on which to work the `:s`, as `:'[,']s///`. This will then work on the region just yanked or pasted. Sure, it's not short, but if you care about it you can map it. Perhaps something like `nnoremap <Leader>p p:'[,']s/`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Another example of how everything you can imagine, vim can do.

Answer (score 3):

Chris Morgan already posted the best solution.  But you can also do some kinds of manipulation directly on the text in the register.  The default register for yank is `"`, so you can do something like:

```
:let @" = substitute(@",'someword', 'somedifferentword','g')
```

Then paste the altered register text.  Not as easy for manipulation related to line-context in multi-line register text, since the text in register is a single string with one begin pattern (`^`) and one end (`$`).  But still can be useful.

Just thought I'd throw it out there, since this is something I sometimes do.